# Avoid for loop in dataframes when committing the csv records to database columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to reading the parameters in csv and committing it to the db using DataFrames.

```
data = pd.read_csv(file)
data.to_csv(str(target_folder) + str(data['project_id'].iloc[0]) + '_' + str(file_name))
project_id = str(data['project_id'].iloc[0])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['project_id', 'class', 'id', 'material'])
for row in df.itertuples():
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO idea2 (project_id, class, id, material) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)",
                    (row.project_id, row.rate_voltage, row.frequency, row.material))
conn.commit()
```

Can we achieve the same without for loop ??

Comment: Any reason for not using [`DataFrame.to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_sql)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the column names match, this should work:

```
df.to_sql("idea2", conn)
```

See: [`DataFrame.to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_sql) for more details.